# How can I get 2 max value from list of objects in Python?

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have this list of objects:

```py
value = [{'a': 0.864}, {'b': 0.902}, {'c': 1.174}, {'d': 1.162}]
```

All I want to do, is just get 2 objects with biggest value, like `{'c': 1.174}, {'d': 1.162}`

I can create such function:

```py
def getTwoMaxValue(obj):
    extractedValues = []
    for i in obj:
        for attr, value in i.items():
            extractedValues.append(value)
    firstBiggestValue = max(extractedValues)
    extractedValues.remove(firstBiggestValue)
    secondBiggestValue = max(extractedValues)
...
```

But as you can see, it seems pretty long. Is there a way on how to do this writing less lines on code?

Comment: If your code works and you're looking for code review, consider posting to [codereview.se]

Comment: you can make a bunch of improvements. 1: you dont need to create an auxiliary array. 2: you just need to keep track of the biggest and 2nd biggest elements when you traverse. 3: you dont need max and remove, which all would go through the array again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
def get_two_max_value(obj, n=2):
    return sorted(obj, key=lambda x: max(v for v in x.values()))[-n:]


value = [{'a': 0.864}, {'b': 0.902, 'e': 100}, {'c': 1.174}, {'d': 1.162}]
print(get_two_max_value(value))
```

Even returns the objects instead of the values themselves.

Comment: Do you need the max values or the objects?
I can re-write the code.